# Multiple file upload using single input controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting upload multiple files in ASP.NET MVC and  my controller is

```
 public ActionResult GalleryAdd()
    {
        foreach (string fil in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fil];
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And my input field is

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

Problem is that always upload only one file(first file) . Foreach loop only take the first file , but Request.Files Count shows number of file uploaded. What is the problem here

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature of your `GalleryAdd` action to take an `IEnumerable` of `HttpPostedFileBase`, then you can iterate over the files passed in from the view:

```
public ActionResult GalleryAdd(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         // iterate over files
     }
}
```

Then add a file input for each file to add:

```
<form action="@Url.Action(GalleryAdd)" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

    <input type="submit"  />
```

Comment: but i want to upload files using a single input field, is that any way in c#

Answer (score 0):

you can write webservice that will be called in controller.
use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145334/not-able-to-split-a-file-and-send-and-then-join-in-server) link for getting help regarding upload file 
also look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581703/how-to-do-a-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-post-with-multipart-form-data) link.