# Uploading files to a server using java

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload

I am writing a simple java servlet to upload files to a server location from any client. This is my servlet doPost method:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(isMultiPart){
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            try{
                FileItemIterator itr = upload.getItemIterator(request);
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    FileItemStream item = itr.next();
                    if(item.isFormField()){
                        String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                        InputStream is = item.openStream();
                        byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
                        is.read(b);
                        String value = new String(b);
                        response.getWriter().println(fieldName+":"+value+"</br>");

                    }else{
                        //String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        String path = <server path>;
                        if(FileUpload.processFile(path, item) ){
                            response.getWriter().println("file uploaded successfully</br>");
                        }else{
                            response.getWriter().println("file uploading failed</br>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(FileUploadException fue){
                fue.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I now have a problem when I am uploading very big files. Incase there is a network error, I need to resend all the files to the server again, I would like to prepare a solution where the user can upload the files from the point where it stopped when the network error occurred.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Can you please put the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The upload just doesnot start from the point where it stopped. It has to be restarted from the beginning.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this? I am looking everywhere for a solution but cannot seem to find anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/).

[Resume uploads from previous sessions](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/01/resume-uploads-from-previous-sessions-in-3-2/).
[File Chunking Partitioning](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2012/12/28/file-chunkingpartitioning-is-now-available-in-3-2/).

Comment: are there any open-source possibilities for the same?

Comment: Do it manually then...refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145334/not-able-to-split-a-file-and-send-and-then-join-in-server for the logic and see the last comment to see his mistake in the question code.

Comment: The above linked library IS open source